# How to get your web application to target ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, server, config

I am having problems installing a web application on the server because it only has ASP.NET 2 and the web application is expecting 4.0,

How can I swap the web application to target ASP.NET 2.0 on the server as I know it can be 2.0 as it was originally built in 2.0.

Is there some configuration somewhere that will tell it which it is ?

Comment: ASP.NET version numbers (originally) tied tightly with the version of .NET. So you'd change your web application to target .NET 2.0. But are you sure that's a good idea? Wouldn't it be easier to install .NET 4.0 on the server and the more modern features and bug fixes?

Comment: The problem is that in out production server it currently only has 2.0 so updating the production server would be a whole new thing. At the moment my project are targeting .NET 3.5 so would this default to asp.net 4.0?

Comment: @mason sorry forgot to tag your name in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the web application is expecting 4.0

If the source is compiled at .Net Framework 4, you cannot downgrade to .Net 2 at Application Pool.

### How to Fix

You want to change the target framework to .Net Framework 2, and publish again.

[image]